# Stuck in infinite loop and I don't know how to get out of it

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-clock

I am stuck in an infinite loop but I'm not sure how to get out of it. I am trying to build a clicker game and want an automatic character to deal damage for me. I haven't spent much time refining it all and it's probably messy and inconvenient, but I am a very new coder and want to get some experience.

I tried to make  `loop` equal to 2 and run an identical while loop, however I did that in the if statement when I know it has to be in the while loop. Just can't figure out how to fix it. Any other tips would also be appriciated!

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
rotation_angle = 180
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 900))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

monster1 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/t_cro/OneDrive/Pictures/Saved Pictures/snail1.png")
monster2 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/t_cro/OneDrive/Pictures/Saved Pictures/fly1.png")
background = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/t_cro/OneDrive/Pictures/Saved Pictures/background.png")
automatic_character_background = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/t_cro/OneDrive/Pictures/Saved Pictures/scrollbackground.png")
automatic_character = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/t_cro/OneDrive/Pictures/Saved Pictures/player_walk_1.png")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (1080, 900))
monster1 = pygame.transform.scale(monster1, (125, 75))
monster2 = pygame.transform.scale(monster2, (0, 0))
automatic_character_background = pygame.transform.scale(automatic_character_background, (500, 820))
monster1_health = 10
monster2_health = 10
death_count = 0
money = 0
cost_character_1 = 50
character_1_amount = 0
red = 255,0,0
text_surface = font1.render("number of monsters killed:", True, red)
money_text = font1.render("money:", True, red)
buy_auto_character_1 = font1.render("buy/upgrade (1)", True, red)
monstercheck = 1
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and monstercheck == 1:
                monster1_health -= 1
                if monster1_health <= 0:
                    print("wow this code actually works")
                    death_count += 1
                    monster1_health = 10
                    monstercheck = 1
                    money += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and monstercheck == 2:
                monster2_health -= 1
                if monster2_health <= 0:
                    print("how have i not given up yet?")
                    monster2_health = 10
                    death_count += 1
                    monstercheck = 1
                    money += 10
---------------------------------error here-------------------------------------------------------
            if event.key == pygame.K_1 and cost_character_1 <= money:
                character_1_amount += 1
            if character_1_amount >= 1:
                loop = 1
                while loop == 1:
                    dt = clock.tick()
                    time_since_last_hit = dt
                    if time_since_last_hit >= 1000:
                        monster1_health -= character_1_amount
                        time_since_last_hit = 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    death_count_blit = font1.render(str(death_count), True, red)
    money_number = font1.render(str(money), True, red)
    monster1_health_blit = font1.render(str(monster1_health), True, red)
    character_1_amount_blit = font1.render(str(character_1_amount), True, red)
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(monster1, (700, 450))
    screen.blit(monster2, (700, 450))
    screen.blit(death_count_blit, (530, 50))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (330, 13))
    screen.blit(automatic_character_background, (30, 50))
    screen.blit(automatic_character, (75, 175))
    screen.blit(money_text, (125, 97))
    screen.blit(money_number, (250, 100))
    screen.blit(buy_auto_character_1, (150, 200))
    screen.blit(monster1_health_blit, (750, 550))
    screen.blit(character_1_amount_blit, (1,1))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You don't update the loop variable, so the loop will continue forever.

Answer (score 0):

Which `if` statement are you using to update the `loop` variable?

There are two rules for the loop to work properly:

1. You should be able to enter the `while` loop, which is happening as
   you have the `loop` variable equal to 1, which is also your while
   condition.
2. You should be able to get out of the `while` loop, which
   would happen by setting the `loop` variable to something that is not
   equal to 1, and this should happen inside the while loop.

As stated in the comment, I do not see the `loop` variable updating inside the `while` loop. You need an `if` condition or something similar that will set the `loop` variable to something other than 1 so that the loop can finish. I also suggest that you add a `print` statement inside the `while` loop and right above the line you update the `loop` variable to see which lines are executed and which lines are not.